# How to avoid formatting for XML, SQL etc. raw strings in clang-format?

Tags: clang-format

I have some C++ code with embedded XML like this:

```
QLatin1String test()
 { 
  return QLatin1String(R"XML(
           <ui language="c++">
             <widget class="Test" name="dialogbuttonbox">
               <property name="text">
                 <string>DialogButtonBox</string>
               </property>
             </widget>
           </ui>)XML");
 }
```

When formatting this with

```
clang-format --style=WebKit test1.cpp
```

Then the xml will be formatted to be broken, because of the definition of RawStringFormat:

> If no style has been defined in the .clang-format file for the
> specific language, a predefined style given by ‘BasedOnStyle’ is used.
> If ‘BasedOnStyle’ is not found, the formatting is based on llvm style.

So I tried the following within .clang-format:

```
RawStringFormats:
  - Language: None
    Delimiters: ['XML']
    DisableFormat: true
```

Which results into the following error:

```
.clang-format:177:15: error: unknown enumerated scalar - Language: None
```

What I really want to avoid is to add comments to the source code to switch formatting off/on:

```
// clang-format off

// clang-format on
```

So my question is how to switch off formatting for XML, SQL or whatever is not supported by clang-format raw strings?

Also what about the above unknown enumerated scalar message? Does it mean that `Language: None` ist not allowed? So maybe I have a feature request?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Which version of clang-format did you use? AFAIK there's no formatting for raw-string-literals at all by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

My fix was to **split the XML sections into their own files**.
The clang formater then doesn't touch them and your standard VS Code formater will be used.

I then needed to set the maxLineWidth to 0 which means no new lines because of column length.

*.vscode/settings.json*

```
    "xml.format.maxLineWidth": 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no formatting issues with raw string literals based on your example in clang-format 14 (default version for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

Unfortunately you didn't mention which version of clang-format you used, so it's tedious to test all of them.

Only 3 line were changed after run the command you provided (I only added `-i` to get inline changes in file):

```
clang-format -i --style=WebKit test1.cpp
```

Here is the diff:

```
 QLatin1String test()
- { 
-  return QLatin1String(R"XML(
+{
+    return QLatin1String(R"XML(
            <ui language="c++">
              <widget class="Test" name="dialogbuttonbox">
                <property name="text">
@@ -8,5 +8,4 @@ QLatin1String test()
                </property>
              </widget>
            </ui>)XML");
- }
- 
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

As you can see, no lines with raw string literal content were modified.